# Bathroom Ceiling Outlet installation from Attic

Tags: electrical, bathroom, receptacle, gfci

I would like to install another outlet in my bathroom so I can hookup a smart speaker. I think the easiest way to do this would be from the attic such that I could place a ceiling outlet from an easy to reach power source.

- Does the outlet need to be a certain distance from the wall, or could
  it be where the ceiling meets a wall?
- Does the outlet need to be GFCI (It will be 6 feet or so away from the
  sink)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All receptacles in a bathroom are required to be GFCI protected. As far as the location away from wall there is no requirement on that it could be touching the I have put them in a corner touching or almost touching 2 walls.

Comment: I recall my electrician several years ago telling me that a heat/light/fan in the ceiling (hardwired, not a plug in receptacle) had to be a certain distance (not far) away from being directly above a tub or shower - that if it was directly above a tub or shower then it would need to be GFCI protected. But receptacles always (and he made sure to take care of that - even though that isn't what I brought him in to do **safety first!**).

Comment: Note that you should be able to take power from an existing outlet that is downstream from your existing GFCI to get that protection "for free".  I'd make it GFCI protected regardless of exact placement in the bathroom.

Comment: A speaker is different than other things like lights and heaters. The receptacle for anything in a bathroom requires GFCI protection. But a powered device for things like speakers have no space requirements that a ceiling heater would have.

Comment: In this case the outlet will not be directly above a tub or sink, but I will use a GFCI protected receptacle just to be safe.